# Strtok and fgets Objective C Functions are causing read errors along with segmentation faults

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets, strtok

Below is the code I currently have to read in data from a file.  When I comment out the while loop and try to just read in one line of the data I get a few null or 0 values printed followed by the rest of the data in a block and a segmentation fault message at the end. When I leave the while loop I get nothing but the segmentation fault message. However, if I choose to just read in the first variable without the loop everything works fine.  Below I have included my code and the test file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BUF_LEN 1024

int main(){

FILE *file;
int i;
char *SywUserId, *IntractnId, *DivNbr, *ItemNbr, *KsnId, *buddy_cnt, *cnt_rank,      *table_type, *summer_active, *winter_active;
char buf[BUF_LEN];

file = fopen( "ea_test_rec.txt" , "r");

fgets(buf, BUF_LEN, file); 
while(!feof(file)) {
    if(strlen(buf) < 2) break;
    i=strlen(buf)-1; while(i > 0 && buf[i] <= ' ') buf[i--] = '\0';
    SywUserId = strtok(buf, ",");
    table_type = strtok(NULL, ",");
    cnt_rank = strtok(NULL, ",");
    IntractnId = strtok(NULL, ",");
    DivNbr = strtok(NULL, ",");
    ItemNbr = strtok(NULL, ",");
    KsnId = strtok(NULL, ",");
    buddy_cnt = strtok(NULL, ",");
    summer_active = strtok(NULL, ",");
    winter_active = strtok(NULL, ",");

    printf("%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s\n", (SywUserId, table_type, cnt_rank, IntractnId, DivNbr, ItemNbr, KsnId, buddy_cnt, summer_active, winter_active));
            fgets(buf, BUF_LEN, file);
}
    fclose(file);
}
```

ea_test_rec.txt

```
1,1,1,-276551,7,63062,0,1.993,0,0,
1,1,10,24315147,54,41796,0,1.934,0,0,
1,1,11,25562371,2,40396,3747849,1.934,0,0,
1,1,12,-948793,2,2820,0,1.919,0,0,
1,1,13,4272725,44,20243,0,1.911,0,0,
1,1,14,2917566,44,71641,0,1.900,0,0,
1,1,15,24655338,54,71593,0,1.898,0,0,
1,1,16,22365342,44,67862,0,1.894,0,0,
1,1,17,12690269,44,14216,0,1.886,0,0,
1,1,18,2920093,44,93074,0,1.875,0,0,
1,1,19,8569801,2,40396,0,1.868,0,0,
1,1,2,-273684,7,63204,0,1.984,0,0,
1,1,20,10171246,88,2379,0,1.859,0,0,
1,1,3,1617035,44,72854,0,1.977,0,0,
1,1,4,12690127,44,14602,0,1.973,0,0,
1,1,5,13064870,44,13666,0,1.966,0,0,
1,1,6,1616493,44,34869,0,1.966,0,0,
1,1,7,1617032,44,72854,0,1.956,0,0,
1,1,8,1616460,44,23337,0,1.950,0,0,
1,1,9,24655107,2,94350,0,1.948,0,0,
```

Comment: Instead of doing two separate `fgets` calls, and loop `while (!feof(...))`, you could combine it into `while (fgets(...) != NULL)`.

Comment: Oh, and nothing here is Objective-C as said in the title.

Comment: As for the problem, have you tried running the program in a debugger? It will stop at the crash, letting you examine and walk up the function call stack to your code, so you can see where the problem is, It will also let you examine the values of variables.

Comment: Your printf statement is not set up correctly.  Not enough params.  And if you check the output of your fgets() statement at the bottom of the while loop, on the very first call, you are getting an error (on my compiler its -1)

Comment: Regarding the comment from ryyker, you might want to learn about [the comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

Comment: As it turns out, my compiler was confused by the extra set of parenthesis surrounding the parameter list in your printf statement.  If you remove them, and pay attention to null terminating your strings, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of your strtok buffers is probably not what you expected.  I would definitely take @Joachim's advice regarding the debugger.  Debugger's are a great friend during dev time.

Following is an image of the string results from strtok()'ing first line buffer:

[image]

Remove the unnecessary *()* from your printf statement...  i.e. change your printf statement from:

```
printf("%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s\n", (SywUserId, table_type, cnt_rank, IntractnId, DivNbr, ItemNbr, KsnId, buddy_cnt, summer_active, winter_active));
```

To:

```
printf("%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s\n", SywUserId, table_type, cnt_rank, IntractnId, DivNbr, ItemNbr, KsnId, buddy_cnt, summer_active, winter_active);
```

Output after making these changes:

[image]